# Highcharts horizontal scrolling bug with datetime type

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts, horizontal-scrolling

I have a highcharts chart in place using v11.
There are two series in two panes: candlestick on the upper / column with volumes on the lower pane.

I want to display the full day, so I've been using datetime type for the x series and defined a tick interval with 5 minutes. So far so good, everything is working appropriate except the scrolling behavior:

- Once I scroll outside of the area where I actually have data and come back in, there is that weird sticky behavior
- Mouse wheel scrolling is not working
- Panning is not working (as it's outside of the data area)

---

[Bug Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/8g745vxr/0/)](https://jsfiddle.net/8g745vxr/0/)

js:

```
// config
const currentDate = new Date();
const dayStart = new Date(currentDate).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
const dayEnd = new Date(currentDate).setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
const tradingDayStart = new Date(currentDate).setHours(9, 25);
const tradingDayEnd = new Date(currentDate).setHours(16, 5);
const increaseMin = 5;
const xTickInterval = increaseMin * 60 * 1000;

let yVolumeTickInterval = 100;
let minTimeWithValue,
    maxTimeWithValue,
    minPriceValue,
    maxPriceValue,
    maxVolumeValue = null;

// config END

// simulation
console.clear();
const data = createData(
    new Date(currentDate).setHours(9, 30),
    new Date(currentDate).setHours(11, 30));

function createData(startTime, endTime) {
    let time = dayStart;
    let rangeStart = null;
    let rangeEnd = null;

    let price = {
        open: 100,
        high: 120,
        low: 90,
        close: 110
    };

    let volume = 500;
    let result = [[], [], []];
    let upDownSwitch = false;

    let i = 0;
    while (time <= dayEnd) {
        if (time < startTime || time > endTime) {
            // ------------- DATA FOR EACH TIME POINT
            // result[0].push([time, null, null, null, null]);
            // result[1].push([time, null]);
            // ------------- DATA FOR EACH TIME POINT
            time = time + increaseMin * 60 * 1000;
        } else {
            if (i % 5 === 0) {
                upDownSwitch = !upDownSwitch;
            }

            result[0].push([time, price.open, price.high, price.low, price.close]);
            result[1].push([time, volume]);

            time = time + increaseMin * 60 * 1000;
            volume = upDownSwitch ? volume + 100 : volume - 100;

            price.open = price.close;
            price.high = upDownSwitch ? price.close + 20 : price.close + 10;
            price.low = upDownSwitch ? price.open - 10 : price.close - 20;
            price.close = upDownSwitch ? price.close + 10 : price.close - 10;

            if (rangeStart == null) { rangeStart = result[0].length - 1; }
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (rangeEnd == null) { rangeEnd = rangeStart + i - 1; }

    return result;
}
// simulation END


// data preparation
if (data) {
    if (data[0]) {
        minTimeWithValue = Math.min(...data[0].filter(x => x[1]).map(x => x[0]));
        maxTimeWithValue = Math.max(...data[0].filter(x => x[1]).map(x => x[0]));

        minPriceValue = Math.min(...data[0].filter(x => x[1]).map(x => Math.min(...[x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]])));
        maxPriceValue = Math.max(...data[0].filter(x => x[1]).map(x => Math.max(...[x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]])));
    }

    if (data[1]) {
        maxVolumeValue = Math.max(...data[1].filter(x => x[1]).map(x => x[1]));

        if (maxVolumeValue > 1000000) { yVolumeTickInterval = 100000; }
        else if (maxVolumeValue > 1000) { yVolumeTickInterval = 1000; }
    }
}
// data preparation END


var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        height: null,
        marginRight: 50,
        panning: { type: 'xy' },
        events: {
            load: function () {
                console.log('loaded');
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(tradingDayStart, tradingDayEnd);
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: xTickInterval,
        minRange: xTickInterval * 5,
        min: dayStart,
        max: dayEnd,
        labels: { format: '{value:%H:%M}' }
    },

    yAxis: [
        {
            height: '80%',
            gridLineWidth: 0.5,
            min: minPriceValue * 0.9,
            max: maxPriceValue * 1.1,
            showLastLabel: true,
            labels: {
                x: 0,
                y: 4,
                align: 'left',
                format: '{value:.2f}',
                style: { fontSize: '9pt' }
            }
        },
        {
            top: '80%',
            height: '20%',
            min: 0,
            max: maxVolumeValue * 1.2
        }
    ],

    series: [
        {
            yAxis: 0,
            type: 'candlestick',
            data: data[0],
            color: '#ed454a',
            upColor: '#8cc176',
            lineWidth: 1,
            lineColor: '#3e3e3e'
        },
        {
            yAxis: 1,
            type: 'column',
            data: data[1]
        }
    ]
});
```

css:

```
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

It is working appropriately if I have data for each time point (with null values for the yAxis).
But I guess that's not what the datetime type for the xAxis was added for -> having a timerange without adding data points for each time:

[Null Datapoint Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/8g745vxr/1/)](https://jsfiddle.net/8g745vxr/1/) (see JS line 45/46)

So is there a way to achieve this behavior without having data for each datapoint on the xAxis like on the 2nd fiddle?
Really appreciate any help!

EDIT: this is already a noted issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/19475

Comment: This issue should be resolved soon. If you have any comments or suggestions, please feel free to post them in the thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/19475